# Using glib without calling g_main_loop_run?

Tags: c, glib

Is it correct to use (parts of) GLib without calling g_main_loop_run? If so, how to identity which parts of GLib I can use like this?

I'm mostly interested in (as referred to by https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/index.html):

1. GLib Data Types;
2. GLib Utilities.

Common sense tells me that there should be nothing there to require GMainLoop (except Timers, may be?), but I'm a complete GLib newbie, and somehow didn't find any explicit statement in the docs when GMainLoop is required and when not.

From "GLib Core Application Support" section I'd like to use Message Logging, but not sure about it interaction with main loop.

For those wondering about why, I use FUSE/osxfuse, which already has its main loop, and I'm not sure how easy it is to deconstruct it and integrate into GMainLoop.

Also, I welcome alternative C library suggestions. Looking through GLib docs I rather like it, but I feel uneasy about it trying to be a framework, rather than a set of libraries.

Comment: You can certainly use the majority of glib's functionality without using the event loop portion. As you expect, the portions that dependd on the event loop are things like timeouts, I/O channel watches, etc... Hash tables and trees, Unicode helpers, process spawning, memory allocation, will all work without the loop. I won't write an answer because I don't have any magic list for you of what depends on the event loop and what doesn't. By the way, I think you should see Glib as a large collection of really useful libraries, not the monstrous integrated framework you seem to be weary of.

Comment: Thanks! Your comment is as good as an answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very little of the GLib code requires the main loop, timers for example are implemented using the system's normal timestamp.

The code that does require the main loop will reference it, such as the [IO Channels](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-IO-Channels.html).  Even then you can see that it's possible to use the IO Channels with or without the main loop, it's your choice.